# Find method in ASP.NET EF Core doesn't work on supposedly tracked objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, entity-framework

### One-liner

`DbSet.Find` returns `null` for an entity recently added by `DbSet.Add`, unless `SaveChanges` is called.

### Details

I'm working on a simple Web application where database is involved. Here is the scaffolding, which I believe is quite standard:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<Database.ApplicationContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=records.sqlite.db"));

// ...
```

```cs
public class ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
    : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Model> Records { get; set; } // Model is a record type, which is the only thing
                                              // different from the official examples, but
                                              // I believe this is unrelated.
}
```

```cs
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class Controller(ApplicationContext context) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("query")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Query(string id)
    {
        var item = await context.Records.FindAsync(id);
        if (item is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(item);
    }

    [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(string id, string message)
    {
        long epoch = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        var item = new Model
        {
            Id = id,
            FirstRecord = epoch,
            Messages = [message],
            RecordTimes = [epoch]
        };

        await context.Records.AddAsync(item);
        // await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Solved it, but ...
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then I made some requests. Firstly `/query?id=123abc`, which got 404. Then `/add?id=123abc&message=test`, and the server responded with 200. Finally `/query?id=123abc` again, but surprisingly I had 404 once more.

I added `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` to `Controller.Add` and it solved the problem. However, I thought `context.Records.AddAsync` would **track `model` and immediately return it for future requests** without looking through the database, as made clear in its documentation.

I indeed got entries of executing database queries in the log, so I think for whatever reason, object tracking isn't working here. The only explanation that I can think of is that a new `Controller` is created for each request, thus a new `ApplicationContext` that doesn't share trackers with others.

Comment: You should save your changes after adding records to the DB. Typically yes, you do get a new controller per request (it is not a "singleton"). Looking at this code I would expect changes are not saved in your Add route and I would expect not find the "added" records in the DB.

Comment: The default lifetime conferred on a context by AddDbContext is "Scoped", btw

Answer (score 1):

For each request you have a new instance of DbContext, so adding an entity to instance one and trying to Find it in instance two will not work.